# Exclude first post (sticky or not) from the loop using query_posts()

Tags: loop, query-posts, sticky-post

I'm using `query_posts( 'offset=1' );` to exclude the first post from the loop. However, if the first post is a sticky post it will be shown and the second (non-sticky) post will not be shown.

Is there any method the first post will be hidden, no matter if it's sticky or not? I can't use `ignore_sticky_posts` because I only want to hide the first one.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just curious but why would you need something like this? Also, [don't use `query_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Comment: I want to style the first post differently and, since I'm using a masonry layout, can't do it with just CSS.

Comment: So you need the rest of the elements to be positioned relative to this post, right? Perhaps the [`stamp  method`](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#stamp) is useful. This may also be good to know in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really need to "exclude" anything. Just make use of the built in loop tracking. `WP_Query` will "remember" where you left off. For example:

```
if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    echo 'firstpost##';
    the_content();
    echo '##endfirstpost';
    break;
  }
}

// do some other stuff

if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    echo 'otherposts##';
    the_content();
    echo '##endotherposts';
    break;
  }
}
```

Or just roll the code into the same loop:

```
if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    if (0 == $wp_query->current_post) {
      echo 'firstpost##';
    else {
      echo 'otherposts##';
    }
    the_content();
    if (0 == $wp_query->current_post) {
      echo '##endfirstpost';
    else {
      echo '##endotherposts';
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really didn't know this. This helps a lot!